# Scala: understanding anonymous function syntax

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I am trying to make sense of a custom Iterator in Scala written by another programmer.
I am having trouble understanding the function declarations.
They look like anonymous functions to me, but I simply can't wrap my head around them fully.

I did some reading about Anonymous Functions in Scala , and I found this resource [http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/133] helpful, but I still cannot read the above functions and make sense of them completely.

Here is the code:

```
class MyCustomIterator(somePath: Path, someInt: Int, aMaxNumber: Int) {
      def customFilter:(Path) => Boolean = (p) => true
       // Path is from java.nio.files.Path
      def doSomethingWithPath:(Path) => Path = (p) => p
}
```

I would like to understand these understand these functions. What is the return type really? What is the body of the function?

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(For the first `def`) The parts after the colon and before the equals sign are the return type. So, the return type is:

```
Path => Boolean
```

Which denotes a function signature.

Now, breaking that down, the item on the left of the arrow is the parameters of a function. The right hand side is the return type of the function.

So, it is returning a function that accepts a `Path` and returns a `Boolean`. In this case, it is returning a function that will accept a `Path` and return `true` no matter what.

The second `def` returns a function that accepts a `Path` and returns another `Path` (the same `Path` in this case)

An example usage would be to use them as follows:

## First method:

```
iter.customFilter(myPath) //returns true
```

or

```
val pathFunction = iter.customFilter;
pathFunction(myPath) //returns true
```

## Second method:

```
iter.doSomethingWithPath(myPath) //returns myPath
```

or

```
val pathFunction = iter.doSomethingWithPath
pathFunction(myPath) //returns myPath
```

Comment: Could add, more usual to see `def customFilter: Path => Boolean = _ => true` and `def doSomethingWithPath: Path => Path = identity`. Is that easier to read?

Comment: Justin, I like your explanation. However, let me get my understanding fully right:   "The item on the left of the arrow is the parameters of a function.  "      - is it "Boolean = (p) => true"    If that is so, how do we interpret this syntax.

Comment: @som-snytt, that is easier to read. Path is the return type, and this thing "Boolean = _ => true" is the return type? What is the underscore _ ? It is like a placeholder, I feel. And what did you mean by: Path = identity                I can't get the Identity part.

Comment: @user3825558, I think something like this is clearer: `def customFilter: (Path => Boolean) = (_ => true)` or `def customFilter: (Path => Boolean) = ((p) => true)`. These are exactly identical to the ones in the original code. Now the parentheses clearly delimit types and expressions, and you can see that `customFilter` is a method returning a function.